# Protractor - need to find a happy meduim between the default behavour and jasmine-bail-fast

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

I can share frustration with a lot of professionals about default protractor behavior on test failure - it just keeps running the tests and you have to wait until it finishes to fix the error.

I read the related posts and came across jasmine-bail-fast solution. Link to related post is provided here: [Exit Protractor e2e test on fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496290/exit-protractor-e2e-test-on-fail)

However, this solution puts me on the other side of the pickle. I do NOT want to terminate the testing suite when it failed to close the confirmation message or ran into similar minor issues.

I would like to have the ability to control when to exit the script via exitonfailure() function or something similar. For instance, if had this block of code:

```
> browser.wait(function() 
>       return browser.isElementPresent(acceptBudgetButton);
>     }, 30000, 'Error - Unable to save budget changes because Accept Budget button is not visible. Terminating test run.');
```

and put exitonfailure() after this block, I want my test run to exit immediately. However, I want to test keep on running if exitonfailure() is not there.

Is there a feasible way to achieve this goal and take control of my own destiny?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the `browser.wait()` success and failure cases appropriately:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(acceptBudgetButton), 30000).then(
    function () {
        // success
    }, 
    function () {
        // failure
        console.log('Error - Unable to save budget changes because Accept Budget button is not visible. Terminating test run.');
        jasmine.getEnv().bailFast();
    }
});
```

Also, look into using [`fail()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32252931/771848) which fails a test.

Comment: Thank you for your response - a lot of useful information!

Comment: I've tried to use fail() function without dealing with bailFast() but only with a partial success...  Will provide more details via a separate question, as they will not fit in comment section...